# The customized font going out of right margin of the page in algorithmic

Tags: fontspec, comments, algorithmic

I am using algorithmic package in latex to write an algorithm. I have customized the font style for the comments to my need. For this I have used the two commands to define `\COMMENT` and `\LONGCOMMENT` given in the MWE. But the long comment is going out of the right margin of the page. Can someone provide with the solution.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\renewcommand\algorithmiccomment[1]{\hfill \texttt{ \eqparbox{COMMENT}{// #1}}}
\newcommand\LONGCOMMENT[1]{\hfill \texttt{\begin{minipage}[t]{\eqboxwidth{COMMENT}}{// #1}\strut \end{minipage}}}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]                     
\caption{Reduction 1 and 2}          
\label{algo1}   
\algsetup{indent=3em}                        
\begin{algorithmic}[1]                   
    \REQUIRE The cluster-node incidence matrix $A$ and the number of nodes $m$ of the instance.
    \ENSURE The re-reduction edges of reduction:1 $E_{R_1}$, the set of reduced nodes $I_{R}$ and the reduced $A$. 
    \STATE $S = A^t \times A: S\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m} $ \COMMENT{Scalar product}
    \STATE $E_{R_1}=\emptyset$
    \STATE $I_{R_1}=\emptyset$  \COMMENT{Index of the nodes to be removed by reduction 1} 
    \FORALL{$ i \in \lbrace 1,\ldots,m \rbrace $}
        \STATE $|\mathcal{C}(v_i)|= S_{i,i}$
        \STATE $Super\_set = \{j\mid S_{i,j}= |\mathcal{C}(v_i)| \}$ \COMMENT{The set of nodes $u$ such that  $\mathcal{C}(v_i) \subseteq \mathcal{C}(u)$}
        \IF{$Super\_set \neq \emptyset$} 
        \STATE {$u_i =$ First element of $Super\_set$}
        \STATE{Add the edge $(v,u_i)$  to the set $E_{R_1}$} 
        \STATE{Replace $S_{i,*}$ and $S_{*,i}$ by $[0,0, \ldots 0]_{1\times m}$ and $[0,0, \ldots 0]^t_{1\times m}$ respectively}
        \STATE{Replace $A_{*,i}$ by  $[0,0, \ldots 0]^t_{1\times n}$}
        \ENDIF
    \ENDFOR
    \STATE{Remove the columns $\{A_{*,j}\mid  A_{i,j}=0, \forall i\}$}
    \STATE{$I_{R}= \{1,2,\ldots m\} \setminus I_{R_1}$}
    \STATE{Remove the rows $\{A_{i,*}\mid  \sum\limits_{j=1}^{m} A_{i,j}<2 \}$} \LONGCOMMENT{These rows represent the clusters $\{ V_i\mid |V_i|<2\}$ i. e. this line apply the reduction:2}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image: See the figure]

Comment: I think your approach is wrong here. While it may seem good to have comments span the same width (therefore starting at the same spot within the code), it causes problems when the pseudocode stretches across that marker. Either the comment will wrap in an ugly fashion, or text will not fit properly. You could let the comments be set and wrap naturally.

Comment: Any updates? Could you add your page margins?